# Good resources for learning tuple calculus?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I've been trying to go over my tuple calculus over and over again for hours and days. What's worse is my professor and tutors are not much help during their hours.

Does anyone know a good place to learn about tuple calculus? I'm having a hard time understanding how to "speak" the language in terms of what I want to get from a database.

Thanks, Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two good books I would suggest:

Theory of Relational Databases by David Maier

Fundamentals of Database Systems by Elmasri and Navanthe

Comment: Maier's book is available online: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~maier/TheoryBook/TRD.html